# How to add a new column in a CSV file

Tags: shell, sed

How to add a new column in a CSV file with column name as date in data fill using a text file in shell script.

Input file: input.csv

```
DESC,20-07,21-07,22-07,23-07,24-07,25-07
A,1,2,3,4,5
B,WD,DSF,GFH,SDF,SDF
C,FG,ZX,CRST,SDF,SEF
```

text file: abc.txt

```
26-07
ew
we
we
```

I want the output file like: output.csv

```
DESC,20-07,21-07,22-07,23-07,24-07,25-07,26-07
A,1,2,3,4,5,ew
B,WD,DSF,GFH,SDF,SDF,we
C,FG,ZX,CRST,SDF,SEF,we
```

I want a script which add daily a column in a CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the `paste` command:

```
$ paste -d',' input abc
DESC,20-07,21-07,22-07,23-07,24-07,25-07,26-07
A,1,2,3,4,5,ew
B,WD,DSF,GFH,SDF,SDF,we
C,FG,ZX,CRST,SDF,SEF,we
```

Or the `pr` command:

```
$ pr -mts',' input abc
DESC,20-07,21-07,22-07,23-07,24-07,25-07,26-07
A,1,2,3,4,5,ew
B,WD,DSF,GFH,SDF,SDF,we
C,FG,ZX,CRST,SDF,SEF,we
```

Comment: Best fit tool for this job is paste, +1

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be awk: 
`awk 'NR == FNR {if(x == 0) {x=1};a[x]=$0;x++;next}{for(z=1; z < x; z++){if (z <= NF){print a[z]","$z} else {print a[z]}}}' input.csv abc.txt > output.csv`

This contemplates the case in which input.csv has more lines than abc.txt has columns.